# Unique ID get selected list

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net

How do i do so i can work on multiple lists? This works if i'm working with one list. (SPSiteDataQuery)

```
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

            SPList myList = web.Lists["Staff News"];

            Guid listItemId = new Guid(HiddenFieldID.Value);

            SPListItem itemToUpdate = myList.GetItemByUniqueId(listItemId);

            TextBox textBoxNickname = (TextBox)DetailsViewShowNews.FindControl("TextBoxNickname");
            TextBox textBoxComment = (TextBox)DetailsViewShowNews.FindControl("TextBoxComment");

            if(itemToUpdate != null)
            {
                itemToUpdate["Nickname"] = textBoxNickname.Text;
                itemToUpdate["Comments1"] = textBoxComment.Text;


                textBoxComment.Text = string.Empty;
                textBoxNickname.Text = string.Empty;

                itemToUpdate.Update();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate through a list of lists in a foreach loop.

```
foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

Or

```
var listOfLists = new List<SPList>();
listOfLists.Add(web.Lists["List 1"]);
listOfLists.Add(web.Lists["List 1"]);
foreach (SPList list in listOfLists)
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: i get Value does not fall within the expected range

Comment: SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
query.Lists = "<Lists>" +
"<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("StaffNews").ID.ToString() + " />" +
"<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("CompanyNews").ID.ToString() + " />" +
"<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("ManagementNews").ID.ToString() + " />" +"</Lists>";
Guid listItemId = new Guid(HiddenFieldID.Value);
foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
{SPListItem itemToUpdate = list.GetItemByUniqueId(listItemId);
itemToUpdate["Nickname"] = TextBoxName.Text;
 itemToUpdate["_Comments"] = TextBoxComment.Text;
 itemToUpdate.Update();
 }